# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Sometimes it works, sometimes it fails

Tags: node.js, sql-server, flutter

I'm building a mobile app with Flutter. I am using a web service written in node.js to connect to the Ms Sql database. I'm making the connection with the dio package. Sometimes when I run the program I don't get any error and what I want to do is working correctly. But sometimes I get the following error.

```
(node:33535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to XX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXX in 15000ms
at /home/business/myapp/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:70:17
at Connection.onConnect (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1012:9)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Connection.emit (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1040:18)
at Connection.connectTimeout (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1254:10)
at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1199:12)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:33535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This 
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate 
the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled- 
rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
(node:33535) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the 
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My Node.js code is like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./databases/dbOnlineBekci');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
const pool = await sql.connect(config);

const rolid = req.query.rolid;
const USERID = req.query.USERID;
const gelenquid_id = req.query.gelenquid_id;
const VARDIYAID = req.query.VARDIYAID;
const BASLANGICLAT = req.query.BASLANGICLAT;
const BASLANGICLONG = req.query.BASLANGICLONG;
const MANUELKISI = req.query.USERID;
const currentDate = req.query.currentDate;

let sorgu = `SELECT SUBE.SIRKETID, SUBE.SUBEID, SUBE.LATITUDE, SUBE.LONGITUDE FROM SUBE`;
if (rolid !== '5') {
    sorgu += `
        INNER JOIN KULLANICI ON SUBE.SUBEID = KULLANICI.SUBEID
        WHERE KULLANICIID = ${USERID}
        AND SUBEGUID = '${gelenquid_id}'`;
} else {
    sorgu += `
        WHERE SUBEGUID = '${gelenquid_id}'
    `;
}
const result = await pool.request().query(sorgu);

if (result.recordset.length > 0) {

    const newRequest = pool.request()
    .input('USERID', sql.Int, USERID)
    .input('SIRKETID', sql.Int, result.recordset[0].SIRKETID)
    .input('SUBEID', sql.Int, result.recordset[0].SUBEID)
    .input('VARDIYAID', sql.Int, VARDIYAID)
    .input('BASLANGICLAT', sql.NVarChar, BASLANGICLAT)
    .input('BASLANGICLONG', sql.NVarChar, BASLANGICLONG)
    .input('SIRKETLAT', sql.Decimal, result.recordset[0].LATITUDE)
    .input('SIRKETLONG', sql.Decimal, result.recordset[0].LONGITUDE)
    .input('MANUEL', sql.Int, 0)
    .input('MANUELKISI', sql.Int, MANUELKISI)
    .input('MANUELZAMAN', sql.DateTime, currentDate);

    try {
        const insertResult = await newRequest.query(`
            INSERT INTO TAKIPMESAI(USERID, SIRKETID, SUBEID, VARDIYAID, BASLANGIC, BASLANGICLAT, BASLANGICLONG, SIRKETLAT, SIRKETLONG, MANUEL, MANUELKISI, MANUELZAMAN)
            VALUES(@USERID, @SIRKETID, @SUBEID, @VARDIYAID, @MANUELZAMAN, @BASLANGICLAT, @BASLANGICLONG, @SIRKETLAT, @SIRKETLONG, @MANUEL, @MANUELKISI, @MANUELZAMAN)
        `);
        res.json(
            {
                "sonuc": "Mesai başlatma işlemi başarıyla gerçekleştirilmiştir."
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.json(
            {
                "sonuc": "Mesai başlatma esnasında hata oluştu.Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. "
                + "Sorunun devam etmesi halinde sistem yöneticisine bilgi veriniz."
            }
        );
    }
} else {
    res.json(
        {
            "sonuc": "Okuttuğunuz koda ait bir firma bulunamamıştır. Yada sizin görev yeriniz burası değildir. "
            + "Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. Sorunun devam etmesi halinde sistem yöneticisi ile iletişime geçiniz.."
        }
    );
}
});

 module.exports = router;
```